# Cross-referencing enums

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, enums

I need to cross-reference enums; from enum `Car` I want to access an array of type `Location` and vice versa. The code below compiles fine but one of the complementary arrays (`carArray` in `Location` or `locationArray` in `Car`) contains merely null values:

```
public enum Car {
    AUDI(new Location[]{Location.SANFRANCISCO, Location.NEWYORK}),
    BMW(new Location[]{Location.NEWYORK});

    private Location[] locationArray;

    Car(Location[] locationArray){
        this.locationArray = locationArray;
    }
}

public enum Location {
    SANFRANCISCO(new Car[]{Car.AUDI, Car.BMW}),
    NEWYORK(new Car[]{Car.AUDI});

    Car[] carArray;

    Location(Car[] carArray){
        this.carArray = carArray;
    }
}
```

When I run

```
 Car car = Car.AUDI;
 Location location = Location.SANFRANCISCO;
```

I get a `locationArray =  [SANFRANCISCO, NEWYORK]` on `car`, but `carArray = [null, null]` on `location`. However, I expect the latter to be `carArray = [AUDI, BMW]`.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Side note: I find it rather awkward to use enums this way - it violates the Single Responsibility Principle: a car is a car; it knows **nothing** about locations. Same is true for locations. You might have another class that combines the two; but as written above ... has the small of bad design.